# RxJS way to build the chain of consecutive api calls

Tags: promise, rxjs

If I deal with an arbitrary array which values have to be mapped to promises and it is crucial to wait for previous call completion before the next one performed, I usually follow this pattern:

```
const later = ms => 
  new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(_ => resolve(console.log(ms)), ms));

console.log('chain start')

let chain = Promise.resolve();
[1, 2, 3, ...].forEach(val => 
  chain = chain.then(later.bind(null, val * 100)))

chain.then(_ => console.log('chain end'))
```

The important parts here are that 1 - we don't know how many items array could carry and 2 - we can't use `Promise.all` (consecutive calls or queue required).

The question is: 
What is the best RxJS way of doing so? So, observables instead of promises.

(I'm aware of `.toPromise`)

Answer (score 3):

assume all your array contains [urls]

```
from([url1,url2,url3...]).pipe(concatMap(url=>defer(()=>fetch(url))))
.subscribe(results=console.log(results))
```

Comment: this assumes `fetch` returns a cold observable.  May be better to do `concatMap(url => defer(() => fetch(url)))` to be safe.

Comment: Also you cannot call `pipe` on an array.  I think you are missing `from([url1, url2, ...]).pipe(...`

Comment: @Brandon I don't think `defer` is needed here even with hot Observables as `concatMap` will only call the given function if the previous Observable completed.